# Seeking design advice for moving a single client's data to a separate database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku

This is a design approach question. As such, it may be too broad. If so, please let me know and I'll take it down.

Here's the background...

I have built an API application that is a front end to a rules engine. I have a set of clients that host their (proprietary) rules in my rules engine. Their clients are able to call my API and perform calculations - submitting a JSON blob of query parameters and receiving back a JSON blob including the result of the calculation along with various alerts as appropriate. I get paid by my clients on a transaction volume basis.

My application is hosted on Heroku.

My normal model is that, related to each API transaction, I store (a) the inbound JSON blob, (b) the return JSON blob, and (c) some metadata about the transaction itself (datetime, result, etc.). I don't do anything in particular with the data except peform analysis on it as requested by my clients. 'Owning' the data and/or using it is not a part of my business model.

Currently, the API transaction data is not encrypted in the database.

Now, I have a client that wants the inbound and return JSON to be stored in a database separate from all other clients' data. And, they want it to be encrypted while at rest.

So, what I'm contemplating doing is the following...

Creating an all-new application whose sole purpose is to store a single client's API transaction data. I'll create an API to this application. And then in a background process (so as to not adversely affect peformace), I'll write the client's API transaction data (from my rules engine application) to the new application using the API. Once confirmed as written to the new application, I'll delete it from my original rules engine application.

Is this a VERY BAD IDEA? I used the Googles and didn't come up with any blinding insights. (For instance, using a Heroku 'follower' database). So thought I'd give it a shot here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems workable as long as your app is specific to storage and is intended to integrate (fully) with the current app. Overall, you should make it so that your clients can easily pay to upgrade their current app to make use of the storage capabilities of the new one.

Although rather than calling it a new app, it seems more like an optional new feature to your current app, which might be the better way to go about it.